# No Template Parameter Needed in Return Type

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, return-type

```
template <typename Type>
class Foo
{
    Foo& Bar()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Why does this compile?  Shouldn't I have to specify the template parameter in the return type?

```
Foo<Type>& Bar()
{
     return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo<Type>` is implied because the definition of `Bar` is within the definition of the class. If it were outside the class definition then you'd have to define it explicitly:

```
template <typename Type>
Foo<Type>& Foo<Type>::Bar()
{
    return *this;
}
```